# How to automatically close CSS comment tag in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to automatically close the "*/" part of css comment after I type /* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using VsCode, If you are using mac, just type want you want commented, then while your cursor is on the same line press cmd + / but on if you are on windows, press ctrl + /